# Some questions are highlighted

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blue highlighted questions, what are they?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/blue-highlighted-questions-what-are-they)

Sometimes I see that some questions are highlighted with kind of light blue color on the main page of math.stackexchange

any explanation as to why they appear so?

Comment: Closing as duplicate. See especially the [answer by Hendrik](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/blue-highlighted-questions-what-are-they/2670#2670)

Comment: @Willie: I didn't realize the system did that, but you're right, that's probably what Bhargav is experiencing.